# What Unique Post References Persist Between Versions of WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am writing a WordPress plugin that uses remote JavaScript at mydomain.com/api.js to interact with my API at mydomain.com and want the JavaScript to have predictable hooks to WordPress posts. What unique post identifying elements or attributes persist unchanged in the WordPress DOM when upgrades are applied from time to time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be too concerned about this; one of the aims of WordPress updates is to avoid breaking backwards compatibility, so it's very unlikely any of the standard post classes will change.

Obviously a good thing to do is, as a minimum, check your plugin against the official themes - e.g. [Twenty Fifteen](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfifteen/). Follow development on http://make.wordpress.org - you can download and test them in advance.

The following pages are a good guide to all the CSS classes:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class
https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/post_class
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_class